# click and create a square where I click in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In my code below I would like, when I click on the square in the "menu" below that it is reproduced in "the workspace" (the top part) at the place where we will click. But for the moment it only moves the square at the same time as the mouse.

I can not solve this problem, can you help me please?

cordially

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#window
window = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,800])
pygame.display.set_caption("ArchiConnect World")

#constantes
clickable_area = pygame.Rect((100,720), (70, 70))
clickable_area2 = pygame.Rect((100,500), (70, 70))
clickable_area3 = pygame.Rect((220,730), (50, 50))
clickable_area4 = pygame.Rect((300, 450), (50, 50))
hold = 0;

#colors
GREEN = (84,173,65)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
rect_draw = 0
x = 100
y = 500

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    event.pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos();
    #menu rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (BLUE), Rect((0,700), (1000,10)))
    #server rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (GREEN), Rect((100,720), (70,70)))
    #server rectangle in board


    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.button == 1:
            if clickable_area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                hold =1

    if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:  # Si mouvement de souris
        # On change les coordonnées du
        if hold == 1:
            carre_x = event.pos[0]
            carre_y = event.pos[1]
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (GREEN), Rect((carre_x, carre_y), (70,70)))

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The title says you want to drag and drop the square, but then you say you just want to create a square where you click. Please clarify what you want to achieve and what problems you have with the implementation.

Comment: alright skrx, it's edit

Answer (score 0):

You could define a list of pygame rects to which you append new rects when the user clicks a mouse button. Then draw the rects in the list with the help of a `for` loop.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,800])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

clickable_area = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (1000, 630))
# Define a list to which we add the pygame.Rects.
rects = []

GREEN = (84,173,65)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if clickable_area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Append a new rect to the rects list.
                rects.append(Rect(event.pos, (70, 70)))

    #menu rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLUE, Rect((0, 700), (1000, 10)))
    #server rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(window, GREEN, Rect((100, 720), (70, 70)))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, GREEN, clickable_area, 3)

    # Draw the rects.
    for rect in rects:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, GREEN, rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: oh thanks, I try to do a loop to insert the square only when I click in the first square in the menu, thanks a lot